# Solving advanced equation

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations

In the grid, which I described in [my last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2063682/399832), every number $x$
 has a unique set of $r$ (row number) and $c$ coloumn number.
$x$ is given and $x \in  \Bbb N$, we want to get $r$.
This formula lets us calculate $x$ based off the row and coloumn number.
$$2^rc+2^{r-1}=x,\; r \in \Bbb N,\; c \in \Bbb N,\; x \in \Bbb N$$

---

False part start

solving this equation for $c$ gives us the following equation:
$$2^{-r}x-\frac{1}{2}=c$$
If we insert this for c in our original equation we get
$$2^r(2^{-r}x-\frac{1}{2})+2^{r-1}=x$$

---

False part end

The part where I'm struggling is to solve this equation for $r$, so I can insert $x$ and get $r$.
I hope somebody can help me with this...

Edit: the equation I made is stupid.
If you were able to follow my thoughts you might got what I'm trying to achieve.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Your last equation is an identity: it holds for all values of $r$. What you've done here is like solving for $x$ in $2x+1=3$, finding $x=1$, then plugging back in to get $2(1)+1=3$.

Comment: Any suggestions then? If look at my last question, you will see the grid I'm talking about. x is any number in the grid, and I want to get the row number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know x, divide x by 2 repeatedly until the result is odd. The number of divisions is r-1.

If you know both x and c, then, noting that x = 2^(r-1))(2c + 1), you get r = 1 + log_2((x/(2c+1)).

Comment: I know that, but I want this number as a formula

Comment: Note that 2c + 1 is the odd part of x (i.e., the largest odd positive integer factor of x), thus c = (odd_part(x) - 1)/2. That's about as close to a "formula" for c in terms of x as you're going to get. Using that, use the form for r given in my answer to get an expression for r in terms of x.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
  2^r\left(2^{-r}x-\frac{1}{2}\right)+2^{r-1}&=x \\
  1x-\frac{1}{2}2^r+2^{r-1}&=x \\
  x-2^{r-1}+2^{r-1}&=x \\
  x&=x
\end{align}
The value of $x$ is independent of the value of $r$ in the equation you've set up. Since you have two variables, you need two *distinct* equations relating $x$ and $r$ to solve for them, where you've only used one.